# Black overlay on image hover and should remain active when we go inside the page

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I'm working with four images every image has a link and when clicked it take us to the another page. Now my problem is that I want to make the black overlay on hovering the image and when the image is clicked and take us to another page it remain active with that overlay.

i have four images on front page and same images on inside pages.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3">
        <a href="#">
            <div id="ImageHover">
                <img src="http://209.236.116.120/~sciallin/it/backend/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/model23.png" alt="" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the `CSS`:

```
<style>
#ImageHover img:hover
{
     background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
</style>
```

its working for me but the overlay is not coming over the image.and i also want that the image remain active with overlay when we goes inside the page which is linked with this image.

the first problem is solved and when inside the page to make the image active with overlay i have done this ->
Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="ImageHover" class="active">
<img alt="" src="http://209.236.116.120/~sciallin/it/backend/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/model23.png">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#ImageHover.active {
    background : rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
    bottom : 0;
    content : ' ';
    left : 0;
    position : absolute;
    right : 0;
    top : 0;
}
```

but it make the image dissappear.and when i block the postion it comes back but back side of image. what should i do now.

Comment: *"its working for me"* - what is working? So when the image is clicked, you are redirecting to another page? If so, obviously you can't keep the overlay in current page. You can show an overlay in the loaded page though.

Comment: @TJ: no dear that was not working but now its working.my next problem is to make that image active with overlay inside the page.

Comment: @TJ: first problem to make the overlay is solved by SimonR's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your current CSS with the following and apply the `.active` class to your box.

```
#ImageHover {
    position: relative;
}

#ImageHover:hover:after,
#ImageHover.active:after {
    background : rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 28px;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 28px;
    content: '';
}
```

I modified the position so that it outlines your box perfectly, but you can change it back if you wish.

Comment: Now thats what exactly i was looking for its even solve the prblem of image width coz my image is having white spaces on both side.thanks a ton dear for ur precious help.

Answer (score 2):

This (or something similar) should give you the effect you are after, at least in modern browsers:

```
#imageHover {
    position : relative;
}
#imageHover:hover:after {
    background : rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.6 );
    bottom : 0;
    content : ' ';
    left : 0;
    position : absolute;
    right : 0;
    top : 0;
}
```

To get the effect to carry over to indicate that the user is on a given page you'll need a class on the relevant `#imageHover` on the page. You can then add `#imageHover.active` as an extra rule after the hover style.

As a side note, you'll probably want to use a class instead of an ID, or you'll need to add a CSS rule for each and every imageHover element.

**EDIT :** the selector for the `.active` class will also need the `:after` pseudo-element. The CSS rule will be something like:

```
#imageHover:hover:after,
#imageHover.active:after {
    /* ...css... */
}
```

Apologies for not making that clear.

[Further reading on pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) (those things rock!)

Comment: :thats working perfectly.now my next problem is that when user click on that image its takes them to anotjer page.where again those images are placed.now i want that image to b active with overlay.how can i achieve that.

Comment: You add your `.active` class to that box that corresponds to the current page.

Comment: Did you add that to the first image on your `sc23-cabin` page?

Comment: @Eliel: i have edited my question please check.when i give the class active it removes the image and when i block the postion from active css it come back but with overlay in back of image please check the edited question

Answer (score 0):

To get the image to be allready active when the next page is loaded, you should load the page with a hash attribute.

Let's say you have 4 pictures, each with a different id, on a page called pictures.html :

```
<img id="image1" class="imageOverlay" src="" />
<img id="image2" class="imageOverlay" src="" />
<img id="image3" class="imageOverlay" src="" />
<img id="image4" class="imageOverlay" src="" />
```

To load the page with the 3rd image active, you call **pictures.html#image3**

Then, in your CSS:

```
.imageOverlay:active {
    /* CSS for image overlay */
}
```

That CSS will apply to the picture having an id that corresponds to the hash in the URL.
The problem you could face is that the browser will scroll to that image on page load. Which is something you may not want.

I don't think there's a way in CSS to avoid that behaviour.